# Docker reserve a certain amount of memory for container

Tags: docker

I'm running `npm` inside a docker container and every so often it aborts because it cannot allocate enough memory. I see some flags like `--memory` ([How do I set resources allocated to a container using docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084741/how-do-i-set-resources-allocated-to-a-container-using-docker)) for the `docker run` command that seem to limit the maximum amount of memory that a container can consume, but haven't seen anything yet that would allow me to reserve an amount of memory for the container and abort immediately if it cannot be allocated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not how memory management works under Linux.

If you run full virtualization, like QEMU, then all memory can be allocated and passed down into the VM. That VM then boots the kernel and the memory is managed by the kernel in the VM.

In Docker, or any other container/namespace system, the memory is managed by the kernel that runs docker and the "containers". The process that is run in container still runs like a normal process but in a different `cgroup`. Each `cgroup` has limits, like how much memory the kernel will hand out to userland, or what network interfaces it sees, but it still runs on same kernel.

An analogy of this is that docker is a "glorified `ulimit`". Processes under this limit still behave as normal Linux processes

1. they allocate memory as-needed
2. they will cause OOM issues if they pass some limit, or host runs out of memory

And just like you can't pre-allocate memory for Firefox, you can't pre-allocate memory for a Docker container.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reserve memory in docker, only limit it with --memory.

See:   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/ for more detail.

Specifically look at the user memory constraints section.

> memory=inf, memory-swap=inf (default)     >>>> There is no memory limit for
>   the container. The container can use as much memory as needed.

Note that's the default.  So like other processes on the system npm will use all it can get/need.

So either free up some memory or add more.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you cannot reserve memory for processes, and therefore containers. However, you could have the node app called from a script that will check the available memory and exit if it is below a certain threshold.